Problem loading transformers; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'
I want to use some of the models available through huggingface. I am having the hardest time even getting started. Can anyone help me identify and solve this problem?
I am using Kubuntu 24.04.

First, I create and activate a virtual environment within which to install transformers.
python3 -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate

This is successful, as now my terminal in Visual Code Studio has the prefix '(.env)'.
Next, I install the latest transformers from github:
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers

The output is successful. I then test its success with the recommended method on hugginface.co:
python3 -c "from transformers import pipeline; print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('I love you'))"

The output looks right to me:
No model was supplied, defaulted to distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english and revision 714eb0f (https://huggingface.co/distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english).
Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended.
Hardware accelerator e.g. GPU is available in the environment, but no `device` argument is passed to the `Pipeline` object. Model will be on CPU.
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9998656511306763}]

From there, I try to run the following code:
from transformers import pipeline

but every time I get the following output:
/bin/python3 /path-to/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path-to/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from transformers import pipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'


To run the main script with your virtual env (not the system python), you should call python3 /path-to/main.py, not /bin/python3 /path-to/main.py. When you activated your venv (.env), .env/bin/python3 is your venv's python binary, and PATH envvar is prepended with your venv's bin path.

Thanks for your comment, cjackal. I am not quite sure how to implement what you suggest. I am not deliberately calling "bin/python3 /path-to/main.py" that. That happens automatically, even while in my venv.
How might I implement what you recommend?

I think I just followed your recommendation by running the the .py from terminal with 'python3 "/path-to/main.py"', rather than clicking "run python file" in Visual Studio Code.
Is there a way to get this to work without running the .py file in this way? Perhaps when running the .py file by clicking "run python file" it VSC isn't using the venv?

Yes you can run your code using run python file in VSC, but you need to make sure VS code use your venv. you can read :
Python environments in VS Code
